# Does a bond pay a coupon at maturity?

Tags: finance, bond, finance-mathematics, zero-coupon, debt

I know a bond pays an annuity cashflow of coupon payments and then at maturity it pays the face value. But, at maturity, does it pay an additional coupon payment on top of the face value or are we supposed to think about this payment of its face value as its final coupon payment?

Comment: Most bonds pay at maturity face value and one final coupon.

Comment: @KurtG. OK, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Zero coupon bonds do not pay coupon. Instead zero coupon bonds pay the face value at maturity. We buy at a discount and at maturity, it pays the face value.

All other fixed income bonds, pay coupon and the original principal at the end.

Comment: Zero coupon bonds trade at a discount if interest rates are positive. But when interest rates are negative, then zcb's actually trade above par.